# Не могу понять JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Начинаю осваивать JavaScript, и у меня ничего практически не получается. Иду по основам, после теории дается задание, которое я не могу выполнить. Читаю задание и впадаю в ступор. Как писать код, что должно быть в функции, чтобы она заработала, с чего начать, как должен выглядеть код, чтобы он был рабочим, как его оформить — мне абсолютно непонятно.

## Например, вот такое задание:

> Реализуйте функцию printJaimesLine, которая принимает один аргумент — строку, и выводит реплику на экран в формате JAIME: переданная_строка.
>
> Как назвать переменную, которая будет аргументом — решайте сами.
>
> Наша система содержит код, скрытый от вас. В этом упражнении скрыт вызов функции printJaimesLine. Так мы проверяем ваше решение.
>
> Вам не нужно самостоятельно вызывать функцию, только определить её.

================

Мой вопрос заключается не в решении данного задания, а как научиться писать код самой? Потому что сейчас я испытываю только беспомощность, как только нужно написать код.

Comment: "как научиться писать код самой?" - пробуя его писать и преодолевая по очереди все маленькие трудности (и опасности), которые Вам встретятся. В качестве моральной поддержки ставлю Вам плюсик.

Comment: К сожалению, дать хороший ответ на такой общий вопрос очень сложно. Кому-то программирование дается легче, кому-то сложнее, но все проходят этап "нужно написать код, а у меня не получается". В таком случае главное не опускать руки и пытаться. Если совсем-совсем ничего не идет, то можно найти готовое решение поставленной задачи и разобрать каждую строчку, а затем написать свой код не смотря на готовое решение. Со временем простые задачи начнут получаться и можно будет пытаться писать что-то более сложное, а там уже и до реальных приложений дойдет.

Comment: смотри сразу ответ и пытайся его понять

Comment: Насколько я знаю, ресурс, на котором ты обучаешься располагает хорошей теорией перед самой практикой. Просто читай внимательнее и делай в соответствии с образцом) а вообще, это нормально на первых порах не понимать, что, блин, происходит) Главное: не бросай это дело. Вместе с прохождением практики ты можешь смотреть какие-нибудь новичковые видео на ютубе, чтобы хотя бы понять как выглядит язык.

Comment: @sonic Не отчаивайтесь ) Igor правильно Вам сказал, что надо подходить к задачам постепенно. В наше время в интернете очень много информации. Самое главное - сохранять оптимизм. ) Самое сложное - это начать, а в дальнейшем освоение выбранного языка программирования станет гораздо легче. Сначала попробуйте порешать задачи с готовым ответом, чтобы при необходимости посмотреть, где Вы могли ошибиться, и как решить ту или иную задачу. Или попросите уделить Вам 10 минут, для объяснения основ для начала обучения. И всё пойдёт гораздо быстрее. Самое сложное это начать. )))Плюсик

Comment: @Air аххах. помню как нас учили синтаксису ассемблера на первом курсе, мало кто понимал вообще о чем лектор вещает. дело далеко не в синтаксисе.

Answer (score 4):

> Подобные вопросы из категории "ни о чем", надо удалять, а не поощрять плюсами... Изучите в первую очередь синтаксис и не будут возникать подобные вопросы, на которые нет ответа....

В психологии есть такое понятие как "проклятие знания" (curse of knowledge), это когнитивное искажение в мышлении человека, суть которого заключается в том, что более информированному человеку крайне сложно рассматривать какую-либо проблему с точки зрения менее информированных людей. За счет того, что у более информированного человека за годы и тысячи часов практики сложились устойчивые нейронные связи и нейронные контуры в головном мозге, позволяющие ему успешно решать рабочие задачи, ему трудно понять проблемы начинающих, он думает: писать код это так легко и просто, что там сложного, изучи синтаксис и у тебя исчезнут все проблемы. Но это иллюзия.

Дело не только в программировании. На самом деле научить любого человека какому-нибудь навыку или профессии — это сложнейшая проблема. Это проблема методологии. Если бы существовала универсальная и успешная методология по преподаванию программирования, то не было бы проблем с нехваткой тех же middl'ов во фронтенде, но их по-прежнему не хватает, несмотря на обилие оффлайн и онлайн-школ.

Те же самые проблемы с кодом у начинающих в других странах:

1) https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-cant-i-understand-javascript

2) https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/i-just-dont-understand-javascript/290673/5

3) https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/i-understand-javascript-but-cant-write-code/176363

4) https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/4o2wpk/i_just_cant_understand_javascript_i_dont_get_why/

5) https://www.quora.com/Why-can%E2%80%99t-I-learn-JavaScript-I-feel-so-bad-and-like-everyone-else-gets-it-so-easy-I-get-stressed-out-and-my-self-esteem-gets-worse-everyday

Подытоживая, пришла к мысли, что надо больше работать с готовым кодом, повторять за другими — из урока в урок идти по плейлисту готового проекта, печатать готовый код из книг.

Answer (score 1):

Просто ищите другой учебник/ресурс. Начните с таких учебников, где автор сам пишет, объясняет свой код и как его запускать, а потом в качестве задания предлагает немного модифицировать его. Т.о. сначала перепечатывается код из книжки (именно печатать, а не copy-paste), а потом допечатываются правки согласно заданию. И не отчаивайтесь! Все придет с опытом.

Answer (score 0):

Причина может быть в самом источнике, где вы изучаете javascript. Мне лично очень помог  https://learn.javascript.ru/ и несколько ютуб-каналов:

-[плейлист с вебинарами по js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2WiaSvOj78&list=PLyeqauxei6jezJsOYzsxZFPv8OJe5fb6a)
 -[javascript решает](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Nlks6JQ0Ck&list=PLM7wFzahDYnG-oMkclNX0FIcLZR18hFDM)

Comment: ответ скорее тянет на комментарий, чем на ответ. но посыл на мой взгляд правильный. возможно стоит начать обучения с другой литературы или источников.

Answer (score 0):

Если чего то не знаешь то гугли* и учись!

> с чего начать, как должен выглядеть код, чтобы он был рабочим, как его
>   оформить — мне абсолютно непонятно.

**google >** как запустить javascript

так ты узнаешь как создать и запустить простейший скрипт.

> Реализуйте функцию printJaimesLine

**google >** функции в javascript

так ты узнаешь как создать функцию, зачем они нужны про ключевое слово function, что у функций есть имена.

> которая принимает один аргумент

**google >** функции с аргументами в javascript

теперь ты знаешь как передать параметр в функцию(аргумент)

> один аргумент — строку,

**google >** строки в javascript

теперь ты знаешь как работают строки javascript,

> и выводит реплику на экран в формате JAIME: переданная_строка.

**google >** как вывести сообщение в javascript

так ты узнаешь про console.log() и другие методы вывода.

Готово теперь ты знаешь как написать программу, если нет, то начинай перечитывать все заново - и так будет всегда, все здесь присутствующие зашли когда то на форум что бы нагуглить решение. Просто разбирай любую задачу на блоки и гугли - постепенно выполняя задание.

*под гуглом подразумевается любой источник информации.